# Appending nodes from two XML documents into one XML document

Tags: xml, r

I am using `LibXML` in `R` for parsing XML files. I can parse the files efficiently in R. Having done this I am facing a problem which goes like this, I have two sets of XML files which have the following structure:

```
<begin>
<sentence>
<text Blah Blah/>
</sentence>
</begin>
```

This is the first file.

The second file looks something like:

```
<begin>
<sentence_additionalinfo>
<text Blah Blah/>
</sentence_additionalinfo>
</begin>
```

I want to nest the `<sentence_additionalinfo>` tag in the `<sentence>` tag, the final structure should be something like:

```
<begin>
<sentence>
<text Blah Blah/>
<sentence_additionalinfo>
<text Blah Blah />
</sentence_additionalinfo>
</sentence>
</begin>
```

Is it possible to perform the above actions using R?
Option of using XLST will be too complicated as I am generating some data dynamically to add.

Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about the R language, but with LibXML2 (in Perl or Python or PHP), in order to import nodes from one document into another one you'll use the `importNode` method. Take a look at this Perl example, it should be easily portable to R:

[Re: join two xml docs with LibXML](http://code.activestate.com/lists/perl-xml/8722/)

Comment: Thanks for some good pointers Michael. I turned to Python to solve this problem.